# ASP.NET and WCF RIA Services

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Makes it sense to use **ASP.NET** applications (or applications which are a micture of ASP.NET and **Silverlight**) together with **WCF RIA Services** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it makes perfect sense. That is the way to obtain data in silverlight apps by design. WCF RIA services makes it even easier and straight forward.

Here a brand new [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsldesigner/building-a-simple-forms-application-using-the-silverlight-tools-for-visual-studio-2010-and-wcf-ria-services) about how these technologies snap together.